# How would learning Latin only to read Latin change the way I should learn it?

Tags: classical-latin

So I studied GCSE Latin but there was no English to Latin on the Exam, we only ever had to read in Latin or translate from Latin into English. So my question is this: If I wanted to learn to read and translate but only going from Latin to English, what should I do differently? Is there anything I should not waste my time learning?

Comment: Are you going to be reading prose only or also poetry?

Comment: @CMonsour Prose

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about reading Latin prose writing (silently) and translating it into English there's a lot you can ignore, especially around the niceties of pronunciation. Also, it's much easier to look up Latin words and find English meanings than vice versa, so if you are only reading Latin and not writing it, a robust vocabulary is not necessary at the start. But you still need to know the grammar cold, or nothing will make sense.

Comment: @C Monsour: Dictionaries usually have  Latin-English & English-Latin sections. How is there any difference in difficulty in looking up words from the one or the other?

Comment: @tony Even when that's the case, there's usually a lot more effort that goes into the Latin-English section.  There's rarely much explanation in the English-Latin section of when to use which Latin word for a particular English word.  On the other hand, Latin-English dictionaries usually give extensive citations explicating the various meanings of the Latin word.